# Чи має запозичений термін “Ресепшн” синоніми українського походження?

Tags: from-english, терміни, синоніми

При візиті до будь-якої організації чи установи нас частенько прохають звернутися на "Ресепшн" з метою отримання будь-якої інформації.

Вікіпедія [пояснює](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%88%D0%BD), що:

> **Ресепшн** (*англ. reception*) — спеціально умебльована зона частини приміщення при вході в офіс компанії, фірми, готелю та інших подібних закладів.
>   Зона ресепшн – це обличчя компанії, місце, куди насамперед звертається клієнт, що заходить в будь-яку установу: будь це офіс, ресторан, перукарня чи готель. Жодна компанія в наші дні не може нормально функціонувати без зони ресепшн.
>   Ресепшн росташовують, зазвичай, на вході, стійка ресепшн немов вітає відвідувача, створюючи перше враження про те, наскільки солідна і надійна репутація фірми.

На Словотворі [надають](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/resepshen):

> **Значення слова**: **Ресепшен** — спільна частина офісу де, як правило, приймають відвідувачів.
>   **Приклад вживання**: *Наш Клієнт, міжнародна торгова компанія, оголошує конкурс на вакансію "Секретаря на ресепшн".*
>   **Варіанти перекладу слова:** приймальня, шинквас, дожидальня, почекальня, рецепція, канцелярія, реєстратура.

Надані варіанти, на мою думку, досить далекі від зазначеного контекстного значення вживаного слова.

Вікісловник поки що про "ресепшн" [не знає](https://uk.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%88%D0%BD&title=%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0:%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA&go=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8&fulltext=1&searchToken=80rsyphbnbm7zmrlhgyokobbc), як і [Офіційний сайт Української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/search/?q=%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%88%D0%BD&t=0), та й "Словник іншомовних слів" [не допоміг](http://www.jnsm.com.ua/cgi-bin/m/ts.pl).

Отже, підсумовуючи викладене, особисто у мене виникають наступні питання:
- чи існують ще варіанти значення терміну “Ресепшн”?
- чи має запозичений термін “Ресепшн” синоніми українського походження?

Comment: [Вахта](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=6778&page=248) (п'яте значення)?

Comment: Мені здається, що "вахта" по перше "росіянізм", а по друге яким чином це слово може підійти? Змісти навіть не подібні.

Comment: Вахта у розмовному значенні - це фактично приміщення де вахтер перевіряє перепустки (тобто у нього одна функція). На ресепшені можуть взагалі не перевіряти особу: якщо знаєш куди тобі треба - часто можеш просто йти у потрібний тобі кабінет.

Answer (score 3):

[ВІТА́ЛЬНЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/vitaljnja), і, жін. Спеціально умебльована кімната для приймання гостей.

Answer (score 1):

[Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/resepshen) також пропонує варіант "[приймальня](http://sum.in.ua/s/PRYJMALjNJa)", а також непогані варіанти - "стійка прийому відвідувачів", "[реєстратура](http://sum.in.ua/s/rejestratura)", "[почекальня](http://sum.in.ua/s/pochekaljnja)" та "[дожидальня](http://sum.in.ua/s/dozhydaljnja)". Також можу припустити, що можливий варіант "[чекальня](http://sum.in.ua/s/chekaljnja)".

Answer (score 0):

Василь Барвінок у [коментарі на фейсбуці](https://www.facebook.com/ukrse/posts/1580230788769628?comment_id=1580231802102860) пропонує варіант **стійка адміністратора**.

І такий варіант справда вживається, наприклад:

- > Стійка адміністратора скидалася на дерев'яну скульптуру в дусі мінімалізму. // [Жан-Крістоф Ґранже «Пасажир» у перекладі Леоніда Кононовича](https://books.google.com/books?id=O2iIDgAAQBAJ&pg=PR4-IA61&dq=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%22).
- > Проти входу розташувалася стійка адміністратора, справа невеликий бар з м'якими кріслами, зліва двері вели у ресторан. // [Петро Лущик «Полювання на дрохв»](https://books.google.com/books?id=O2iIDgAAQBAJ&pg=PR4-IA61&dq=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%22).
- [Результати пошуку в «Google Книгах»](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%22+OR+%22%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%22+OR+%22%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%83+%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%22+OR+%22%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E+%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%22+OR+%22%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%86%D1%96+%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%22).
- [Результати пошуку в корпусі «ГРАК»](http://kontext.parasolcorpus.org/view?q=~73hkNNXT0ACm&corpname=grac5).